# Property 'frame' not found on object of type 'UISearchBar' error

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

**What I am trying to do**: I want to move the x and y coordinates of my search bar on a touch event. I have placed my code in viewDidLoad to test it out. However I am getting an error.

**Error:** Property 'frame' not found on object of type 'UISearchBar'.

**My code:**

```
NSNumber *newX = @0;
NSNumber *newY = @0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
    [UISearchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(newX, newY, UISearchBar.frame.size.width,
                                       yourSearchBar.frame.size.height)];
}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {}
 ];
```

Ultimately I would like that animation/move to be executed when the search bar is selected and then move back after deselect.

Comment: Replace `UISearchBar` with a variable of type `UISearchBar *`.

Comment: You are also passing `NSNumber` instances to a function, `CGRectMake()`, that takes `CGFloat`s. That should be `CGFloat newX = 0;` and `CGFloat newY = 0;`.

Comment: When I make a variable of UISearchBar do I need to assign that variable to the search bar some how?

Answer (score 0):

`UISearchBar` is a class. It doesn't have a class method `setFrame`. It does have an instance method though and that's what you should be using. So, you need an instance of `UISearchBar`, either that you already have or you need to create one.

If this is being done when the search bar is selected, your code would be in the delegate method `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:` and you would use the supplied parameter:

```
[searchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(newX, newY, searchBar.frame.size.width, yourSearchBar.frame.size.height)];
```

Comment: You still have a `UISearchBar` reference in the middle.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy, not sure what `yourSearchBar` is in there either but I left that for now...

Comment: How would I create an instance method of UISearchBar?

Comment: You don't want to create an instance method, you want an instance to call the method on. Presumably you have an instance created in XIB / storyboard?