# Objective-c, property 'frame' not found on object of type AVPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avplayer

I'm trying to code a video player in Objective-C using XCode & a guide, but I'm getting an error for some reason, and I'm quite new to Objective C, the exact error code is - `Property 'frame' not found on object of type AVPlayer.`

Viewcontroller.h

```
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet AVPlayer *avPlayer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableString *frame;
```

Viewcontroller.m

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"vid" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
    self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileURL];

    AVPlayerLayer *layer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.avPlayer];
    self.avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
    layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768); //error point
    [self.view.layer addSublayer: layer];

    [self.avPlayer play];
}
```

I've been following this guide - http://jacopretorius.net/2013/02/playing-video-in-ios.html after trying multiple others.

My question is, why doesn't declaring the 'frame' work, I've also tried multiple ID's for the AVPlayer object & different ways to code the video player.

I've also tried -

[Stackoverflow error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926239/error-property-frame-not-found-on-object-of-type-uiview)
[Stackoverflow error 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846660/property-frame-not-found-on-object-of-type-uisearchbar-error)

Comment: Did you forget `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`?

Comment: @trojanfoe nope it's there

Comment: Ah that is most unusual then...

Comment: I can't find a different method of doing this, even though this should work

Comment: Are you certain that's the exact code?  The error message states you are attempting to use `AVPlayer.frame` and not `AVPlayerLayer.frame`.

Comment: In theory, your error should say `Property 'frame' not found on object of type AVPlayerLayer` (in the case of `AVPlayerLayer` doesn't have a `frame` property). So it's taking `layer` as a `AVPlayer` object and not a `AVPlayerLayer` one.

Comment: I'm currently answering from my windows laptop, I've typed it over from my mac.

Comment: @trojanfoe thank you, I actually typed it over correctly, but coded it incorrectly, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message states you are attempting to use `AVPlayer.frame` and not `AVPlayerLayer.frame`, so I think you've mis-typed the code with something like this:

```
AVPlayer *layer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.avPlayer];
^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Could you help me for a second, perhaps in a room? @trojanfoe